# Using vertical-align to vertically center a button within a div

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, vertical-alignment

Goal is to center a button within a div, both horizontally and vertically. Horizontal has been dealt with, but having trouble with vertical align.

From the [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) on `vertical-align` it states that using `middle` has the following result:

> "The element is placed in the middle of the parent element"

In my problem ([see jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bhcoLg9h/2/)) I have set the CSS of a button within the parent element (to the best of my knowledge) to be vertically aligned.

**HTML:**

```
<div id='titleSection'>
  <div class='title-inner right quarter-width'>
    <form action='destroy.php' method='POST'>
        <button>Log Out</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class='title-inner left quarter-width'>
    <!--nothing-->
  </div>
  <div class='title-inner center half-width'>
        <h1 class='centered-text'>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
font-family:'Arial', Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    padding: 2.1vh 0;
    font-size: 6vmin;
}

div#titleSection {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12vh;
    border: 2.5px solid #ff0fff;
}

div.title-inner {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
}

div.quarter-width { width: 25%; }
div.third-width { width: 33.3%; }
div.half-width { width: 50%; }

div.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

div.center {
    float: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

div.right {
    float:right;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.title-inner button {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Am I wrong to think that the parent element is the `title-inner` div?

I have also tried setting the CSS to:

```
.title-inner form { vertical-align: middle; }
```

to no avail.

To recap: All extra CSS and html shown in jsFiddle just to give most accurate idea of what I am trying to do - apologies if this is unnecessary but I'd rather leave it in to avoid losing track of where I am. End goal is simply to (vertically) center the **Log Out** button within the right-hand (blue) div.

Comment: One advice, make your structure with flexbox...you will achieve what you want with less css rules and more flexibility. - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Except that flexbox doesn't work in IE <11, so it is almost never a viable solution.

Comment: w3schools docs are pretty terrible. Use the Mozilla Dev Network (MDN) docs instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align  Note also from the docs that "The vertical-align CSS property specifies the vertical alignment of an **inline or table-cell** box." so unless your elements are inline or table cells, vertical-align does not do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vertical-align` property is pretty hard to work with and just a bit painful to be honest. A much more reliable way to center is the method shown here: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

I have implemented this below.

Or use flexbox as Luis said if you can support it.

```css
* {
font-family:'Arial', Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    padding: 2.1vh 0;
    font-size: 6vmin;
}

div#titleSection {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12vh;
    border: 2.5px solid #ff0fff;
}

div.title-inner {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
}

div.quarter-width { width: 25%; }
div.third-width { width: 33.3%; }
div.half-width { width: 50%; }

div.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

div.center {
    float: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

div.right {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.title-inner button {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id='titleSection'>
  <div class='title-inner right quarter-width'>
    <form action='destroy.php' method='POST'>
        <button>Log Out</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class='title-inner left quarter-width'>
    <!--nothing-->
  </div>
  <div class='title-inner center half-width'>
        <h1 class='centered-text'>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea; this is a good, short method for achieving the vertical alignment desired. **However:** I stated at the beginning of the question that I needed it to be horizontally centered too ad your edit seems to change the horizontal alignment. From my testing I've discovered that it is to do with `position: absolute;` on tte child (button) element but I cannot seem to find a way to keep both centered. You may notice the leftmost point of the button is centered - is there a simple edit to make this the centerpoint? Thanks again

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot that this would break you horizontal centering. I have updated my answer to use the same principle for horizontal centering.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use JS to vertically center, it seems less complicated to me than CSS workarounds. I've updated your fiddle with my method: https://jsfiddle.net/bhcoLg9h/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div id='titleSection'>
  <div class='title-inner right quarter-width'>
    <form action='destroy.php' method='POST' id="button1">
        <button>Log Out</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class='title-inner left quarter-width'>
    <!--nothing-->
  </div>
  <div class='title-inner center half-width'>
        <h1 class='centered-text'>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var OuterHeight = $('#titleSection').height();
    var InnerHeight = $('#button1').height();
    var TopMargin = (OuterHeight-InnerHeight)/2;
    $('#button1').css('margin-top', TopMargin);   
});
```

Comment: I should have said that this requires Jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

You should set display:table for parent div

```
div.title-inner {
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
display: table;}
```

And set

```
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
```

for `.title-inner form`

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @andy-furniss for reaching the answer to the vertical alignment problem by editing the CSS of the child element as follows:

```
.title-inner button {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

However the element no longer remained horizontally centered with this method. After some playing around with this method I realised that the left edge of the button is the point being used for horizontal central alignment. By adding a transformation in the x-direction, the element was shifted to the correct position:

```
.title-inner button {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

See snippet below:

```css
* {
font-family:'Arial', Arial, sans-serif;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    padding: 2.1vh 0;
    font-size: 6vmin;
}

div#titleSection {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12vh;
    border: 2.5px solid #ff0fff;
}

div.title-inner {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
}

div.quarter-width { width: 25%; }
div.third-width { width: 33.3%; }
div.half-width { width: 50%; }

div.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

div.center {
    float: center;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

div.right {
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.title-inner button {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id='titleSection'>
  <div class='title-inner right quarter-width'>
    <form action='destroy.php' method='POST'>
        <button>Log Out</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class='title-inner left quarter-width'>
    <!--nothing-->
  </div>
  <div class='title-inner center half-width'>
        <h1 class='centered-text'>Title</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```